# Unhandled Exception: PlatformException(NativeAdError, Can't find NativeAdFactory with id: listTile, null, null) in Flutter

Tags: flutter, runtime-error, native, ads

Any one have idea of this I have use this plugin google_mobile_ads: ^2.3.0
Displaying native ads but getting error on that.
Unhandled Exception: PlatformException(NativeAdError, Can't find NativeAdFactory with id: listTile, null, null) in Flutter

Comment: Now ads package provide Native ads functionality

Comment: FInally, I was able to add native ads to my flutter app. It's not straightforward but it works.
We have to make some files in the Android directory to fix this issue.